# Turning multiple lines into one line with comma separated (AWK)

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like :

Log_file:

```
PROFILE INDEX                    10

PROFILE NAME                Profile_name1

PLMN NAME         PLMN         PLMN NAME         PLMN      
                  INDEX  ALLOWED                     INDEX  ALLOWED

Name1              2       NO        name3             3     NO        
name2              4       NO        name4             5     NO        

PROFILE INDEX                    11
PROFILE NAME                Profile_name2

PLMN NAME         PLMN         PLMN NAME         PLMN      
                  INDEX  ALLOWED                     INDEX  ALLOWED

Name5              2       NO        name3             7     NO        
name6              4       NO        name4             8     NO
```

I want to conver it into CSV.

Output required:

```
Pofile Index,Profile Name,PLMN_ Name,PLMN_INDEX,Allowed
10, Pofile_name1,   Name1,      2,  no
10, Pofile_name1,   Name3,      3,  NO
10, Pofile_name1,   Name4,      5,  NO
10, Pofile_name1,   Name2,      4,  no
```

please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Effort required: some code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -f convert.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input file, and `convert.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=", "
    print "Profile Index", "Profile Name", "PLMN_Name", "PLMN_Index", "Allowed"
}

/^PROFILE INDEX/ {
    ind=$3
    next;
}
/^PROFILE NAME/ {
    sub(/^PROFILE NAME/,"")
    name=$0
    next
}

/^PLMN NAME/ {
    getline;    getline
    d=1; next
}

d==1 {
    pname[1]=$1; pind[1]=$2; all[1]=$3;
    pname[3]=$4; pind[3]=$5; all[3]=$6;
    d++;     next
}
d==2 {
    pname[2]=$1; pind[2]=$2; all[2]=$3;
    pname[4]=$4; pind[4]=$5; all[4]=$6;
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        print ind, name, pname[i], pind[i], all[i]
    }
    d=0;      next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use like this:

```
awk -vRS="" -vOFS=',' '$1=$1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not giving required output.          Output received  :PROFILE,INDEX,10,PROFILE,NAME,Profile_name1
PLMN,NAME,PLMN,PLMN,NAME,PLMN,INDEX,ALLOWED,INDEX,ALLOWED
Name1,2,NO,name3,3,NO,name2,4,NO,name4,5,NO,
PROFILE,INDEX,11,PROFILE,NAME,Profile_name2
PLMN,NAME,PLMN,PLMN,NAME,PLMN,INDEX,ALLOWED,INDEX,ALLOWED
Name5,2,NO,name3,7,NO,name6,4,NO,name4,8,NO,

Comment: Could you try this:- awk -F'\n' '{if(NR == 1) {printf $0} else {printf ","$0}}' somefile ?

Comment: Output:
PROFILE INDEX                    10,PROFILE NAME                Profile_name1,,PLMN NAME         PLMN       PLMN NAME         PLMN      ,                  INDEX  ALLOWED                     INDEX  ALLOWED,,Name1              2      NO        name3             3     NO        ,name2              4      NO        name4             5     NO        ,,PROFILE INDEX                    11,PROFILE NAME                Profile_name2,,PLMN NAME         PLMN       PLMN NAME         PLMN      ,                  INDEX  ALLOWED                     INDEX  ALLOWED,,Name5              2      NO        n